# paintComponent() TextField causes Infinite loop (itself + parent)

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

After several days of research, I beg to ask your help. The following code works but generates significant CPU consumption. It seems that this simple text field executes "paintComponent" in a loop, not only its own, but also its parent (JPanel). Could you give me a way to correct that?

Thank you :)

```
package view;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import constants.Colors;
import constants.Polices;
import constants.Spacing;

public class FieldText extends JTextField 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4526307090633268880L;
    private int xheight = 96;
    public Boolean hinted = false;                      // Définit si le     contenu == au hint ou si le contenu a été entré par l'utilisateur.
    protected Color bgColor = Colors.INPUT;             // Background normal.
    protected Color textColor = Colors.TEXT_INPUT;      // Couleur du texte normal.
    protected Color bgHinted = Colors.INPUT;            // Background lors que le placeholder est actif.
    protected Color textHinted = Colors.TEXT_INPUT;     // Couleur du texte placeholder.
    protected Font textFont = Polices.INPUTS;           // Police texte utilisateur.
    protected Font textHintFont = Polices.INPUTS_HINT;  // Police     placeholder.

    public FieldText()
    {   
        super();
        init(null, null);
    }


    /**
     * @param text String Texte du champ (valeur) 
     * @param text String PlaceHoler
     */
        public FieldText( String text, String hint )
        {   
            super();
            init(text, hint);
        }

    /**
     * @param hint Sting Texte du champ (valeur).
     */
        public FieldText( String hint )
        {   
            super();
            init(null, hint);
        }


    private void init( String text, String hint )
    {
        setOpaque(false);
        setBackground(bgColor);
        setForeground(textColor);
        setMinimumSize( new Dimension( 200, 64 ) );
        setBorder( new CompoundBorder (
                                                BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 5, 0, 0, Colors.GREEN), 
                                            new EmptyBorder(     Spacing.PADDING_INPUTS )   
                                       ) 
        );
        setFont( Polices.INPUTS );

        if ( text != null && text.length() > 0 )
        {
            setText(text);  
        }

        setHeight(-1);          // Height by default.
    }


    /**
     * Définit la hauteur de l'élément. 
     * @param height int Hauteur à attribuer à l'élément. -1 pour utiliser la hauteur par défaut (xheight).
     */
        public void setHeight( int height )
        {
            setPreferredSize( new Dimension(this.getWidth(), (height>-1)     ? height : xheight) );
        }


    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {       
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

        GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint (
            0, 0, new Color( 255, 255, 255, 50 ),
            0, 20, new Color( 179, 179, 179, 50 ) 
        );

        g2d.setPaint( gp );
        g2d.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1, 10, 10);

        super.paintComponent(g2d);

        System.out.println("======> inside FieldText.paintComponent() ");
    }
}`
```

JTextField is in JPanel in JFrame.

Sorry for my bad english ...

[Here a little example who causes the loop.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dY85rIEUrADFnvAWnhA3JasjwpAyMnNw)

EDIT : 
Exemple integration in src/views/GuestLoginView

[Here is the full src](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Obq34CKvix337AGWHZJKRcXfTUuY7YUb)

Comment: `GradientPaint` is notoriously time consuming.  A better approach might be to paint the `GradientPaint` to a `BufferedImage` and simply paint it when you need it.  Problems arise as you need to take into consideration when to create the buffer.  Also, because you're doing a vertical gradient, you might get better performance out of generating a image which is only 1 pixel wide and the scaling it (horizontally) to find the component's width

Comment: This may not solve you problem, but you should be calling `super.paintCompoent()` as your first statement.

Comment: *"JTextField is in JPanel in JFrame."* Post a [mre] as an [edit] to the question.

Comment: WJS : Done ! Andrew Thompson : done ;)
MadProgrammer : Sure, i wiil do that, But why the parent (JPanel) is repainted with the field ? And how avoid that ?

Comment: @ChristianSavels *"But why the parent (JPanel) is repainted with the field ?"* - `setOpaque(false);` will do that - when you also consider the fact that the text field will need to be painted on each time the caret blinks on then off, that could be having adverse effects

Comment: You haven't posted an [mre]. The code should be posted in the forum.

Comment: @ChristianSavels  I reposted your code with some suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running your program doesn't cause high CPU consumption for me.

Also the TextField probably needs constant repainting to animate the blinking cursor. One repaint every second is a reasonable expectation and it is what I see on my console.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
With this code the use of the cpu is correct because it does not take into account the rest of the graphical interface. In my application there are many more elements that are refreshed at the same time and the cpu can then go up to more than 20% without doing anything, just to display a form.

Comment: @ChristianSavels If you can send me a different example that runs with high CPU or your application I can take a look but in general try to look for expensive operations in the overridden paintComponent methods. Also an infinite repaint loop can be caused by changing the property of a the component in the paintComponent method which marks the component for repaint and causes continuous repaints.

Comment: Thx to spend time with me !

Here is the full src folder :

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Obq34CKvix337AGWHZJKRcXfTUuY7YUb


Login page uses more CPU (or validate, or register)
Path : src/views/GuestLoginView

This apps can't work alone, server is needed (local).

Comment: @ChristianSavels From what I see, nothing jumps out as the single reason for high CPU but you do have a lot of little things that probably contribute to the overall problem as your application has grown quite large. The problems arise when 1) you do a lot of stuff in the paintComponent methods 2) you somehow mark the component for repaint in the paintComponent method. For 1) you have to remove any unnecessary calls, calculating things that remain constant shouldn't be there, although the JVM probably optimizes that.

Comment: @ChristianSavels Creating GradientPaint is an example. So try to extract to some constant and just reuse it. For 2) you have to not change the component properties in the paintComponent method. In your code some examples can be found in the Buttons (setForeground(txt) will mark it for repaint), PanelPolygon, HomeEditProfile and HomeNewUser. Anything with a set...() should not be there. The paint methods should ideally be used only for rendering the component, not using it as an extra Thread as everything there will slow down the swing thread which will cause your app to seem slow.

Comment: @ChristianSavels Finally, there could be a third reason you see high CPU consumption, as you mentioned a server. It depends on what kind of server you mean but it could be the one using the CPU.

Comment: @ alxk745 :"Also an infinite repaint loop can be caused by changing the property of a the component in the paintComponent method which marks the component for repaint and causes continuous repaints."

That's the way to find the problem ! Thx

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your code more concisely to put it (mostly) in one file to simplify this. First,
the constant repainting is caused by the blinking of insertion carat. But to do what you want you with the `gradientPaint` it is best to use `JLayer`.  A couple other things to facilitate your code.

1. Don't extend JFrame.  Its methods are rarely overridden so there is no need to do so. Just use an instance.
2. Instead of using `init()` called by the constructor, simply have multiple constructors call the main constructor using `this`.  Like `this(null, null)`

`JLayer` allows Swing components to draw on their children.  This is exactly what you want to do in your program.  I have included this link so you can see the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html) and the accompanying video.  I used the names of the field that were in the video to help follow the explanation in your own code.  And finally, when I ran this I did not see but a `2% CPU` utilization over all of my processes on `Windows 10 with a quad core i7 processor`.

```java
    package view;

    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Font;
    import java.awt.GradientPaint;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;

    import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
    import javax.swing.JComponent;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLayer;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
    import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
    import javax.swing.plaf.LayerUI;

    import constants.Colors;
    import constants.Polices;
    import constants.Spacing;

    public class TestFrame {
       private static final long serialVersionUID = 818148271075948079L;
       private TestPanel         panelContent;
       private FieldText         field1, field2;

       JFrame                    frame            = new JFrame();

       public TestFrame() {

          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          field1 = new FieldText("your text 1", null);
          field2 = new FieldText("your text 2", null);
          panelContent = new TestPanel();
          panelContent.add(field1);
          panelContent.add(field2);
          LayerUI<JComponent> layerUI = new MyLayerUISubClass();
          JLayer<JComponent> jlayer = new JLayer<>(panelContent, layerUI);

          panelContent.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 256));
          frame.add(jlayer);
          frame.pack();
          frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          frame.setVisible(true);
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
          new TestFrame();
       }

    }

    class MyLayerUISubClass extends LayerUI<JComponent> {
       @Override
       public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
          super.paint(g, c);
          Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

          GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(0, 0, new Color(255, 255, 255, 50),
                0, 20, new Color(179, 179, 179, 50));

          g2d.setPaint(gp);
          // g2d.fillRect(0, 0, c.getWidth() - 1, c.getHeight() - 1);
          g2d.fillRoundRect(0, 0, c.getWidth() - 1, c.getHeight() - 1, 10, 10);

          System.out.println("======> inside FieldText.paintComponent() ");
          g2d.dispose();
       }

    }

    class TestPanel extends JPanel {
       private static final long serialVersionUID = -4236642932453746731L;

       public TestPanel() {
          setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
          setBackground(Color.black);

       }

       @Override
       protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          super.paintComponent(g);

          System.out.println("======> inside TestPanel.paintComponent() ");
       }
    }

    class FieldText extends JTextField {
       private static final long serialVersionUID = 4526307090633268880L;
       private int               xheight          = 96;
       public Boolean            hinted           = false;               // Définit si le contenu == au hint ou si le contenu a été entré par
                                                                         // l'utilisateur.
       protected Color           bgColor          = Colors.INPUT;        // Background normal.
       protected Color           textColor        = Colors.TEXT_INPUT;   // Couleur du texte normal.
       protected Color           bgHinted         = Colors.INPUT;        // Background lors que le placeholder est actif.
       protected Color           textHinted       = Colors.TEXT_INPUT;   // Couleur du texte placeholder.
       protected Font            textFont         = Polices.INPUTS;      // Police texte utilisateur.
       protected Font            textHintFont     = Polices.INPUTS_HINT; // Police placeholder.

       public FieldText(String text, String hint) {
          setOpaque(true);
          setBackground(bgColor);
          setForeground(textColor);
          setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 64));
          setBorder(new CompoundBorder(
                BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 5, 0, 0, Colors.GREEN),
                new EmptyBorder(Spacing.PADDING_INPUTS)));
          setFont(Polices.INPUTS);

          if (text != null && text.length() > 0) {
             setText(text);
          }
          setHeight(-1); // Height by default.
       }

       public FieldText() {
          this(null, null);
       }

       public FieldText(String hint) {
          this(null, hint);
       }

       /**
        * Définit la hauteur de l'élément.
        * 
        * @param height
        *        int Hauteur à attribuer à l'élément. -1 pour utiliser la hauteur par
        *        défaut (xheight).
        */
       public void setHeight(int height) {
          setPreferredSize(new Dimension(this.getWidth(), (height > -1) ? height
                : xheight));
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you all for the time spent on my problem.
I'm trying to apply your advice tonight and come back to you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

It was not in the field, but in the paintComponent() of my custom button.

I had

```
  ImageIcon bicon = ( mouseHover ) ? new ImageIcon( iconHover ) : new ImageIcon( icon );
        setIcon(bicon);
        getIcon().paintIcon( this, g2, getIconX(), getIconY() );
```

==> **setIcon** in the **paintComponent** was **not a good idea**, it caused the loop and CPU usage.

Thank you for your useful advices.